# Pytorch crop method not padding the output

Tags: python, pytorch, python-imaging-library

Im using the crop method from the torchvision transforms library. The description of the method as seen here (https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html) says that if the height or width are larger than the image that it will be padded with 0's.

However when I use the function it is not padding. The input as seen here

```
x = torch.rand(1,3,256,256)
y = TF.crop(img=x,top=0,left=0,height=300,width=300)
y.shape
```

results in

```
torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 256])
```

The output I would expect is something that has height and width of 300.

Answer (score 0):

> if the height or width are larger .. will be padded with 0's ..

That is fine, but if you read the [full sentence](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html#torchvision.transforms.functional.crop), it says

> If image size is smaller than output .. padded with 0 and ***then cropped***

It will crop the image after padding, that's why you are not seeing the dimension of 300.